# Not being reduced the workload

Tags: communication, management

There are around 10 people in my team. We are tech workers and everybody is responsible for their tech area. No two people are responsible for the same area. We work with clients. There are 2 big client segments and the distribution of work is around 50-50% either area. My area is currently most in demand - the demand is huge.

We were told today that we aren't to work with 1 of the 2 customer segments anymore. Or more precisely that every time a request from one of the segments comes, the tech person who received it should ask our bosses if they should work on that. Only in exceptional situations the request will be granted. This means -50% of work for most of us and is needed given recent layoffs.

The exception was made for my area. Given the strategic significance of my area for the company I am still to work with both the segments. No exception ruling is needed. I am just to work with all the companies just like till now.

My overtime isn't paid and there are really a lot of requests - it's not possible to do everything in the 8h I'm paid for. Also, I don't see it as fair that I'm the only one to do so much more than the others, having exactly the same job (and probably being paid something similar) as them.

I've asked my boss how I should limit my work several times in the past and always receives an answer in the vein of "Don't bring me problems, bring me solutions - who should take the work from you? Find somebody and make them do it".

How would you tackle that?

Comment: "Don't bring me problems, bring me solutions - who should take the work from you? Find somebody and make them do it". - Hire someone.

Comment: Bosses never tell you how to limit your work. Friends do. Don't finish all the requests and let them pile up. Or look for another job.

Answer (score 6):

Ask your boss to announce to the rest of the team that given the criticality of your areas of responsibility, you get to assign them tickets from it.
Come up with some title for the new role and ask you be promoted to that.

Assigning your overflow tickets in a round-robin fashion should only increase the individual workload by about 10% which is doable.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't already have a request ticketing system, implement one.  If you do have one, make use of it.  Log all requests.  Then prioritise them.  Then work on the highest priority tickets first.

In reality, the low priority ones won't get done, but you only have 8 hours per day.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom line is you are working in the dying business.  Healthy businesses listen very closely to employees that are engaged in business areas of "strategic significance", especially those that are customer facing.

The comment from your boss of "Don't bring me problems, bring me solutions" indicates he is under pressure to cut costs and increase profits and he is out of ideas.

So move on, or establish boundaries.  Implementing a ticketing system with priorities is a good idea, or meet with your boss each day to ask for a priority.  Do the higher priories first, then go home after 8 hours.

You are not a slave and employers do not have the right to treat you as one.